# Python datatable - collection in a column

Tags: python-3.x, py-datatable

Can python datatable have any collection as datatype for a column?

```
import datatable as dt

dt_with_collection = dt.Frame(A=range(5), B=[1,5,7,2,3], c=[(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8), (9,10)])
print(dt_with_collection)
```

```
TypeError: Cannot create column from a python list: element at index 0 is of type <class 'tuple'>. If you meant to create a column of type obj64, then you must request this type explicitly
```

I get this error when trying to do so.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Kindly add an example with better explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the types in `types`

```
dt_with_collection = dt.Frame(
    A=range(5),
    B=[1,5,7,2,3],
    c=[(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8), (9,10)], 
    types=[dt.Type.int32, dt.Type.int32,dt.Type.obj64]
)
```

Its not straightforward to work with columns of type `obj64`, although other SO experts will be more knowledgeable about this than me.  You could do something like this:

```
c_codes = (1,2,5,6)
data_with_collection["inTarget"] = np.array([set(x[0]).issubset(c_codes) for x in data_with_collection["c"].to_numpy()])
```

Comment: How do i perform any operation on column c? for example, if i have a list like c_codes = [1,2,5,6], how do i check if each row c have values all in c_codes?

Comment: I'm not sure you have great options for actually working with a column of type obj64 - see updated answer